# VMware Workstation 10.0.5 MSI failed

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-installer

I am upgrading to VMware Workstation 10.0.5 from 10.0.4. The upgrade process has removed 10.0.4, however when trying to install 10.0.5, I get an error:

```
The MSI 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\VMware_1422579427\vmwareworkstation_x64.msi' failed.
```

I have done the following with no fruit:

1. Followed everything at http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031302, and at the link for 'cleaning up after an incomplete uninstallation on a windows host'
2. Copied the 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Temp\VMware_1422579427\' directory to another location and ran the command

   ```
   msiexec.exe /i vmwareworkstation_x64.msi EULAS_AGREED=1
   ```

   however I got a different error:

   ```
   Failed to install the hcmon driver.
   ```
3. Ran CCleaner's registry cleaner
4. Tried to (re)install VMware 10.0.4, however I still got the 'the msi failed' error

I found two logs, available at https://app.box.com/s/fg993l5rixzkce83fm3uye5elq7z7tdy. I have searched everywhere without finding anything, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem. After removing the registry keys mentioned here https://communities.vmware.com/thread/415441?start=0 I could remove the product and then install it again.